# Formatting different telephone numbers

Tags: typography, critique

I am someone who is not a designer, but tries to make a decent visit card for himself. 
Naturally, I struggle with formatting my phone numbers on it.

One number is French, and it looks like:

> +33 XX XX XX XX

The other is Russian, looks different:

> +7 XXX XXX XX XX

I am not sure whether they look fine or not on the card. How can I improve their layout aesthetically?

P.S. Any other advises will also be greatly appreciated.

[image: visit card]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As each of your phone numbers comes along as a rather regular block (in particular the first one), there is some dissonance as those blocks are not aligned. Moreover the pluses at the beginning do not look well aligned with the numbers.

To alleviate the first problem, you can use lowercase numbers, which are less regular and thus raise less expectations of regularity:

[image]

If the typeface you use for these purposes is aimed at regular instead of technical text¹, this should also give you a plus that is more fitted for this occasion.

Finally, lowercase numbers add some visually graspable structure to your phone number that makes it easier to type it from your card.

<sup>¹ such as Computer Modern, which you are using now and which will probably be the most boring typeface you can use for this audience</sup>